# Wordpress - Fatal error: Call to a member function get_var() on a non-object $wpdb

Tags: php, wordpress

[[Solution by s_ha_dum on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com]](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/91848/storing-password-functions-php)

I'm trying to direct users to a certain post based on a password entered in post settings. I have almost working code:

Form on page:

```
<form method="post" action="">
  <input type="password" name="passwordfield">
  <input type="hidden" name="homepagepassword" value="1">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Code in functions.php

```
function doPasswordStuff(){
    if(isset($_POST['homepagepassword'])){
    $post_password = $_POST['passwordfield'];
    $post_id = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare("SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_password = %s", $post_password) );
    $q = new WP_Query( 'p=$post_id' );
    if($q->have_posts()){
        while($q->have_posts()){
            $q->the_post();
            wp_redirect(get_permalink());
            die();
        }
    } else {
        // oh dear, there isnt a post with this 'password', put a redirect to a fallback here
        wp_redirect('http://www.google.com');
        die();
    }
    wp_reset_query();
    }
}
add_action('init','doPasswordStuff');
```

However I'm getting fatal error (Fatal error: Call to a member function get_var() on a non-object) on this line:

> $post_id = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare("SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts
>   WHERE post_password = %d", $post_password) );

If would really appreciate if someone would take a look :) thanks!

Comment: could you share the error please

Comment: Sorry, I just edited post here it is: Fatal error: Call to a member function get_var() on a non-object)

Comment: did you gloabalize wpdb? before using it use `global $wpdb`

Comment: I tried adding global $wpdb; after function start but than I'm  redirected to last post no matter what password I type.

Comment: globalize $wpdb before this `$post_id = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare("SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_password = %s", $post_password) );
    $q = new WP_Query( 'p=$post_id' );`

Comment: @LuckySoni you should put this as an (the) answer.

Comment: LuckySoni, I tried that but still not working.

Comment: do you still get an error?

Comment: No, not anymore but no matter which password I enter I'm being redirected to the same (last) post.

Comment: try wp_redirect(the_permalink());

Comment: In this case I get blank page with URL to last post in database.

Comment: just FYI.. it is a best practise to use lowercase table/column names.. modify the select query and replace ID with id..

Comment: Thanks. But arrrg no matter what I do the function just directs me to the first post on my blog.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

globalize $wpdb before this

`global $wpdb`

`$post_id = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare("SELECT id FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_password = %s", $post_password) ); $q = new WP_Query( 'p=$post_id' );`

Also it is a best practise to use lowercase table/column names

and then redirect like so

`<?php if ( $q->have_posts() ) : while ( $q->have_posts() ) : $q->the_post(); ?>`

`wp_redirect( the_permalink() );`

`<?php endif;?>`

Also use a http status code as the second parameter to wp_redirect()
This might be helpful
[HTTP STATUS CODES](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/HTRESP.html)

Comment: +1 @Mrozh if you found Lucky's answer helpful, please give it an upvote by clicking the up-arrow next to his answer.  And if it solves your problem/answers your question, you should click the "tick" to accept it.  Welcome to SO! ;-)

Comment: @Sepster, thanks :)
I'm very glad you're helping me guys but I'm still looking for real solution.

BTW: Can't vote yet :(

Comment: @Mrozh You _have_ been given a real solution, for _the problem that you asked about in your original post_.  It appears that you now have a _new_ problem, so you should raise a new question that is nice and clean, that relates specifically to the new problem.  You can reference this question if you think it will help, although this history might just cloud your new issue.  You can't expect a single person to debug your entire application ;-)

Comment: @Mrozh Re "Can't vote yet :(" fair call! :-) But you can accept (which will give you more rep) ;-).  Asking a new question (well) will also get you more rep.

Comment: Ok I did that. And I understand that people won't debug my entire application. If it was major issue I would try to find different solution. In this case I really think it's something minor and since I'm front-end developer and not really into PHP I thought someone will find a problem quickly. Thanks for your advises I will open new question. Good day.