# Error updating Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I was trying to update Wordpress following the next steps.

1. Backup your stuff
2. Turn off caching plugins
3. Update themes/translation files
4. Update Wordpress

All steps worked except 4. At step 4 i got the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object in
>   /var/www/vhosts/mymainsite.nl/dev2.mymainsite.nl/wp-content/object-cache.php
>   on line 51

I'm glad I made a backup and updated Wordpress on a test environment, but i still need to know what is causing this.

All help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

-Kevin

Someone marked this as a duplicate, then linked me to this post as the answer: [Wordpress - Fatal error: Call to a member function get_var() on a non-object $wpdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15548816/wordpress-fatal-error-call-to-a-member-function-get-var-on-a-non-object-wp)

I fail to see how this is my answer?

Comment: @jay blanchard this is different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be possible due to the Step No. 2, So Try commenting that line.
/var/www/vhosts/mymainsite.nl/dev2.mymainsite.nl/wp-content/object-cache.php on line 51

Hope this will help you

Comment: Commenting which line?